# Google Map does not moving to the new LatLng location

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an Android app which traces the path from current location to a specific destination. It works well. But there is an exception scenario.

When user clicks on a destination marker, it needs to move the map to another location with zoom. But only get zoomed without moving to the second location.

This is my relating code segment with that. If you can please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

```
double Kumana1_Latitude = 6.573022;
double Kumana1_Longitude = 81.666875;

double Kumana2_Latitude = 6.649353;
double Kumana2_Longitude = 81.770114;


final LatLng Kumana = new LatLng(Kumana1_Latitude, Kumana1_Longitude);
final LatLng Kumana2 = new LatLng(Kumana2_Latitude,Kumana2_Longitude);

Marker Kumana_marker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .title("Kumana National Park")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN))
    .position(Kumana));
    Kumana_marker.showInfoWindow();

     mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker m) {

                //here it get Zoomed, but does not move to the new location
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Kumana2, 13));

                m.remove();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Tap on the Kumana National Park entreance", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    });

            }
```

Comment: Did you try with `animateCamera`? https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)

Answer (score 1):

Put the marker in `onLocationChanged()` and plot the marker. First remove the marker and then add the new marker with the new location.

All this code must come under `onLocationChanged()`
Check first

```
(if marker == null){
//plot marker
}
else{
//remove first marker..
//add new marker
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `super.onMarkerClick(m)` in your overriden function ònMarkekClick(Marker m)`.